# How to sort two different object list which has name property common

Tags: java

How to sort object which has two different types of object list property. both the list are type of different objects.

```
public class Member {
    private List<Group> groups;
    private List<Person> persons;
}

public class Group {
    private String groupName;
}

public class Person {
    private String personName;
}
```

Is there way to sort these two list and get combined result which will be sorted based on the name.

```
expected result
groupName : alex
personName : bob
groupName: christan
groupName: Dan
perosnName: Kat
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there... why?

Comment: Create an interface that both `Group` and `Person` share, e.g. `Named`, that exposes a `.getName()` method. Then just create a `Comparator<Named>` instance. Alternatively have `Named` extend `Comparable<? extends Named>` and make `Group` and `Person` mutually comparable. As `Joe C` implies, neither of these may be good patterns (why should they be grouped together as similar concepts?), but it's easy enough to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
abstract class BaseClass implements Comparable{ // you could name this class as you want
    protected String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(((BaseClass)o).name);
    }
}

class Group extends BaseClass{
    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "groupName : " + name;
    }
}

class Person extends BaseClass{
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "personName : " + name;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        groups.add(new Group("alex"));
        groups.add(new Group("christan"));
        groups.add(new Group("Dan"));

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("bob"));
        persons.add(new Person("Kat"));

        List<BaseClass> members = new ArrayList<>();

        members.addAll(groups);
        members.addAll(persons);
        members.sort(BaseClass::compareTo);

        members.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

> groupName : alex
>
> personName : bob
>
> groupName : christan
>
> groupName : Dan
>
> personName : Kat